# Problems with loading a map (for a game) from an array

Tags: java, android, arrays, graphics

I am using text files to store maps, but loading them in is giving me a little bit of trouble. The objects are squished together, and I'm not sure why. Here is the "map" file (level_1_1.map):

```
"level_1_1.png", ?600:400?;
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0; 
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 ,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1;
1,1,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1;
1,1,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1;
1,1,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1;
1,1,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1;
1,1,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1;
0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0;
0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0;
```

And here is the class where I load it in:

```
package org.awesome.Models;



public class Map{
int playerWidth = 50;
int playerHeight = 50;
int platformWidth = 20;
int platformHeight = 20;

int playerX, playerY;
List<Platform> platforms = new ArrayList<Platform>();
Bitmap bg;
int backgroundX, backgroundY;

private Context context;
private SurfaceView game;
public Map(Context context, SurfaceView game){
    this.context = context;
    this.game = game;
}

public void update(){

}

public void draw(Canvas canvas){

    for(Platform p : platforms)
        p.draw(canvas);
}

public boolean loadMap(String filename){
    //load the file into a string
    byte[] buffer = null;
    try {
        AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
        InputStream fis = am.open(filename);
        buffer = new byte[fis.available()];
        fis.read(buffer, 0, fis.available());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    String s = new String(buffer);
    //seperate the map image, the dimensions and the mapping itself
    s = s.substring(s.indexOf("\"") + 1);
    String bgname = s.substring(0, s.indexOf("\""));    
    bg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(bgname);
    s = s.substring(s.indexOf(",") + 1);
    s = s.substring(s.indexOf("?") + 1);
    String dimensions = s.substring(0, s.indexOf("?"));
    //actual dimensions
    int width = Integer.parseInt(dimensions.substring(0, s.indexOf(":")));
    int height = Integer.parseInt(dimensions.substring(s.indexOf(":") + 1));

    s = s.substring(s.indexOf(";") + 1);
    String[] mapRows = s.split(";");
    //the actual mapping of things
    String[][] map = new String[mapRows.length][];
    for(int i = 0; i < mapRows.length; i++){
        map[i] = mapRows[i].split(",");
    }

    //now create the stuff
    for(int r = 0; r < map.length; r++){
        for(int c = 0; c < map[r].length; c++){
            map[r][c] = map[r][c].trim();
            int currentDigit = Integer.parseInt(map[r][c]);
            int x = c * 10;
            int y = r * 10;

            //Will create the object at the top left corner of the !!RECTANGULAR!! map representation.
            if(currentDigit == 0){

            }else if(currentDigit == 1 && isTopLeft(1, r, c, map)){
                Bitmap texture = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(game.getResources(), org.awesome.AndroidGame.R.drawable.brown_block_reg);
                Log.w("making platform", "" + x +  ", " + y);
                platforms.add(new Platform(x, y, texture));
            }else if(currentDigit == 2 && isTopLeft(2, r, c, map)){
                playerX = x;
                playerY = y;
            }else if(currentDigit == 3){

            }else if(currentDigit == 4){

            }else if(currentDigit == 5){

            }else if(currentDigit == 6){

            }else if(currentDigit == 7){

            }else if(currentDigit == 8){

            }else if(currentDigit == 9){

            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}

private boolean isTopLeft(int item, int r, int c, String[][] map){
    //width and height measured in # of map "steps" (10px ea)
    int width = 1;
    int height = 1;

    if(item == 0){

    }else if(item == 1){
        width = platformWidth/10;
        height = platformHeight/10;
    }else if(item == 2){
        width = playerWidth/10;
        height = playerHeight/10;
    }else if(item == 3){

    }else if(item == 4){

    }else if(item == 5){

    }else if(item == 6){

    }else if(item == 7){

    }else if(item == 8){

    }else if(item == 9){

    }

    //counts backwards and upwards to see how many blocks of the same type preceed it.
    int curR = r - 1;
    int prevWidthCount = 0;
    int prevHeightCount = 0;
    while(curR >= 0 && map[curR][c].equals("" + item)){
        curR -= 1;
        prevWidthCount += 1;
    }
    int curC = c - 1;
    while(curC >= 0 && map[r][curC].equals("" + item)){
        curC -= 1;
        prevHeightCount += 1;
    }


    if(prevWidthCount % width == 0 && prevHeightCount % height == 0){
        return true; 
    }

    return false;

}

public int countObjectsLeft(String[][] map, int r, int c){
    int counter = 0;
    while(c >= 0){
        if(isTopLeft(Integer.parseInt(map[r][c]), r, c, map))
            counter++;
        c -= 1;
    }
    return counter;
}
public int countObjectsUp(String[][] map, int r, int c){
    int counter = 0;
    while(r >= 0){
        if(isTopLeft(Integer.parseInt(map[r][c]), r, c, map))
            counter++;
        r -= 1;
    }
    return counter;
}

}
```

Here is the result (the pipe characters are where each block ends), and the ball is the player (not loaded from file currently).[image]

I am stuck on this, it seems like blocks should fit the (0, 0) to (19, 19) and (20, 20) to (39, 39). Any help on this would be greatly appreciated :D:D

edit 1:

Here is the platform class in full:

```
package org.awesome.Models;


public class Platform {
private int x, y;
private Bitmap texture;
public Platform(int x, int y, Bitmap texture){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.texture = texture;

}

public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
      canvas.drawBitmap(texture, x, y, null);
      canvas.drawText("|", x + texture.getWidth(), y - 2, paint);
  }

public int getX(){
    return x;
}

public int getY(){
    return y;
}

public Bitmap getBitmap(){
    return texture;
}
}
```

Comment: My first guess is you're doing something in `Platform` as part of the draw function that we need to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code I see your are using dimmensions in pixels, while BitmapFactory.decodeResource performs scalling of your bitmap to fit current device screen density, this couses drawn images to be bigger that should. If you want to use pixels then you should disable scalling in decodeResource using options (setting inScaled  to false should suffice) version:

```
decodeResource(Resources res, int id, BitmapFactory.Options opts)
```

or put your drawables in

```
drawable-nodpi
```

folder, what will prevent scalling during loading

Comment: the inScaled = false didn't work for some reason. I don't have a drawable-nodpi in my project, can I just create it?

Comment: yes create it, I suppose your bitmap is still scalled during drawBitmap, your canvas is at other density. I think you should stay away from using pixel dimmensions - you game screen will look very small on high density devices.

Comment: the plan was to make the maps really big & have a viewport. Is there an alternative way to do it (other than pixels)? I'm not very experienced with this stuff and would like to learn.